# Checking injective function domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=x^2-2x-1$ $ \forall x\in \Bbb R$. Let f:($-\infty ,a] \rightarrow [b,\infty)$, where 'a' is the largest real number for f(x) to be injective. Find the value of (a+b).

Comment: Just plot the function.

Comment: It basically is asking the value of a and b

Comment: I know it parabola of type $y=x^2$

Comment: Can you come up with an (analytical) condition for the function to be injective?

Comment: If you complete the square, it should become clear what $a$ and $b$ must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will only be injective if we intersect it with some horizontal line and there will only be one point of intersection. Basically, since it's a parabola, we only want one half of a parabola. Let's cut it in half at its maximum/minimum value. If you use differentiation you can prove this very easily, but every extremum of a parabola $Ax^2 +Bx +C$ is of the form $x=\frac{-B}{2A}$. The $x$ corresponding to the extremum of this particular parabola is thus $\frac{2}{2}=1$. This is the $a$ you were looking for, $a=1$. Now we also have that this outputs a minimum, because $A>0$ , and our minimum is located at $f(1)=-2$, so $b=-2$. Try to plot it and you will see that if you "cut" the function at these values you will have an injective function (left half of a parabola).

Another approach as suggested in the comments is to complete the square:

$x^2 -2x-1=(x-1)^2-1-1=(x-1)^2-2$. We observe that when $x=1$, this is minimal, which is at value $y=-2$. For any other value of $x$, since squares tend to be positive, we will always end up with a higher value.

$(a+b)=1-2=-1. $